# Use ajv-formats with fastify

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajv, fastify

Playing with fastify and the schema object on routes, I'm trying to add more validations. fastify use (for body validations) [ajv](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv). Following fastify documentation and code, to add a ajv plugin I need to do this:

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({
  ajv: {
    plugins: [
      require('ajv-merge-patch')
    ]
  }
})
```

The documentation is [here](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Validation-and-Serialization/#ajv-plugins)

The problem is that when we try to add this plugin, I receive this error: `Cannot read property 'code' of undefined"` and this is the stack error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined
  at addFormats (/test-api/node_modules/ajv-formats/dist/index.js:30:26)
  at Array.formatsPlugin (/test-api/node_modules/ajv-formats/dist/index.js:15:5)
  at ValidatorCompiler (/test-api/node_modules/fastify/lib/schema-compilers.js:42:16)
  at buildCompilerFromPool (/test-api/node_modules/fastify/lib/schema-compilers.js:20:22)
  at Boot.<anonymous> (/test-api/node_modules/fastify/lib/route.js:269:39)
  at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
  at Boot.emit (events.js:327:22)
  at /test-api/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:153:12
  at /test-api/node_modules/avvio/plugin.js:269:7
  at done (/test-api/node_modules/avvio/plugin.js:201:5)"
```

I get this error with this piece of code:

```js
const server: FastifyInstance<Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse > = fastify({
  ignoreTrailingSlash: true,
  logger: true,
  ajv: {
    plugins: [
      require('ajv-formats')
    ]
  }
})

async function run (): Promise<string> {
  server.addHook('onRoute', (options) => console.log(options))

  await server.register(helmet)
  await server.register(cors)

  return server.listen(3000, 'localhost')
}
```

Has anyone been able to use `ajv-formats` with fastify or could you help me, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What versions are you running?

Comment: I'm running fastify@3.9.2 right now

Comment: Could you add some schemas? Because I have a working example with this plugin but can't replicate your error

Comment: The error comes without routes and nothing, for example, with this code, I get the error:

```
async function run (): Promise<string> {
  server.addHook('onRoute', (options) => console.log(options))

  await server.register(helmet)
  await server.register(cors)

  return server.listen(3000, 'localhost')
}
```
With this code, I get the error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and decided to look into the cause. The problem is that `ajv-formats` depends on `ajv 8.x.x` while `fastify` depends on `ajv 6.x.x`. These two are incompatible.

There are multiple solutions

- Wait for `fastify` to support `ajv 8.x.x`. This is a [work in progress](https://github.com/fastify/ajv-compiler)
- Copy out the required validators, bundle them up in a custom `ajv`-Plugin and add that to `fastify`. A plugin is a function that takes the `ajv` instance as first parameter<sup>1</sup>. There you can add the formats, take a look at `ajv-formats` to see how it is done there.
- Use an older version of `ajv-formats`. Sadly the last version of `ajv-formats` to support `ajv 6.x.x` is [0.2.0](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv-formats/tree/v0.2.0) (take a look at package.json). Not a good option IMO

<sup>1</sup>Plugins can also take options but there are no Typescript typings to add such plugins to `fastify`.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue so I decided to use Ajv version 8.x.x and use other plugins within.

```js
import Ajv from "ajv";
import ajvFormats from "ajv-formats";
import ajvErrors from "ajv-errors";

const ajv = new Ajv({
  removeAdditional: true,
  useDefaults: true,
  coerceTypes: true,
  allErrors: true
});

ajvFormats(ajv);
ajvErrors(ajv, { singleError: true });

export { ajv };
```

After that, I've just used this Ajv instance for schema compilation in the Fastify server as suggested in the [the docs](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Validation-and-Serialization/#validator-compiler).

```js
fastify.setValidatorCompiler((opt) => ajv.compile(opt.schema));
```

It works without any problems. The same result is achievable with regular JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here a working example you may customize:

```
    "ajv-merge-patch": "^4.1.0",
    "fastify": "^3.9.2",
    "fastify-cors": "^5.1.0",
    "fastify-helmet": "^5.1.0",
```

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({
  ignoreTrailingSlash: true,
  logger: true,
  ajv: {
    plugins: [
      require('ajv-merge-patch')
    ]
  }
})

fastify.register(require('fastify-cors'))
fastify.register(require('fastify-helmet'))

fastify.addSchema({
  $id: 'mySchema.json#',
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    foo: { type: 'string' },
    bar: { $ref: '#' }
  },
  additionalProperties: false
})

fastify.post('/', {
  schema: {
    body: {
      $id: 'mySchemaExtended.json#',
      $merge: {
        source: { $ref: 'mySchema.json#' },
        with: {
          properties: {
            baz: { type: 'number' }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, (req, reply) => { reply.send({ echo: req.body }) })

fastify.inject({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/',
  payload: {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: {
      foo: 'foo2',
      evit: 'this'
    },
    baz: 42,
    evict: 'this too'
  }
}, (err, res) => {
  console.log(res.json());
  // shows
  // { echo: { foo: 'foo', bar: { foo: 'foo2' }, baz: 42 } }
})
```

Comment: how can add ajv options as a plugin with `fastify-cli`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Seems to be that my problems come from another part of my code. Creating a new project form 0 and using format seems to works well and I don't need to install ajv-format, because fastify has the option format to use in your schemas!

Thanks to all!